Error Inicial al Descargar Android Studio ("Could not move temporary workspace to immutable location")
Al descargar Android Studio con la configuración predeterminada me aparece el error:
**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A build operation failed.
Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\GCS.gradle\caches\transforms-4\30875eea6872baddd3705431d8e2737f-9e1959ee-ab3e-4522-95c7-73ed457e02c2) to immutable location (C:\Users\GCS.gradle\caches\transforms-4\30875eea6872baddd3705431d8e2737f)


Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\GCS.gradle\caches\transforms-4\30875eea6872baddd3705431d8e2737f-9e1959ee-ab3e-4522-95c7-73ed457e02c2) to immutable location (C:\Users\GCS.gradle\caches\transforms-4\30875eea6872baddd3705431d8e2737f)**

Es posible que sea un problema con las versiones de gradle que no me permite una version inferior a la 8.7. No se que hacer ya que solo me ocurre en este dispositivo. Gracias.
Edit. Uso la versión mas reciente la 2024.1.2. Adjunto imagen de mi gradle.properties

¿Que versión de Android Studio descargaste?, agrega el contenido de tu archivo gradle.properties

Si necesitas algo más estoy a tu disposición. Gracias.

Definitivamente es un problema de caché de Gradle, te sugiero cerrar Android Studio y en tu explorador de windows ir a
C:\Users\<usuario>\.gradle\caches

elimina el contenido del directorio \transforms-4

Ingresa nuevamente a Android Studio.
